# Undefined Variables Within a Package During Build

Tags: go

I have two files within one package named `db`, one of which has a few unexported variables defined. Another one is a test file and would need to use these variables like so:

(This is the structure of the project)

```
$GOPATH/src/gitlab.com/myname/projectdir   
├── main.go
└── db
    ├── add.go
    └── add_test.go
```

(Here is a terse variation of the files)

**db/add.go**

```
package db

func Add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

// some other functions that use a and b from `add_test.go`
```

**db/add_test.go**

```
package db

import (
    "testing"
)

var (
    a = 1
    b = 2
)

// test function use variables from add.go
func testAdd(t *testing.T) {
    result := add(a, b)
    if result != 3 {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Running `go test` within `db/` directory passed, but once I ran `go run main go` it produced the following error:

> db/add.go:: undefined: a
>   db/add.go:: undefined: b

Seems like `add.go` cannot find `a` and `b` from `add_test.go` during the build.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gitlab.com/myname/projectdir/db"
)

func main() {
    res := db.Add(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Is this because `add_test.go` is not included during the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way how go tool works.

`_test.go` files are compiled only when you run `go test`. When a package is imported from another package any code from its `_test.go` files is not used.

Try running `go build` or `go install` from inside db package. It will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths are touchy in Go.  For one, I think you need to prefix them with `import "./db"`.  Another thing is that you should be in your $GOPATH/src location.

Try this:

- move your files under the `$GOPATH/src/project` and `$GOPATH/src/project/db` directories.
- prefix your import path with `./db` for the DB package.

As for the IDE, that's all up to whatever plugins you are using.  Try running the tools yourself: `golint`, `go vet`, `oracle`, etc to see the actual go warnings and errors.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting I use relative import like `./db` in every file within `db`?

Comment: Your code example was incomplete.  I was assuming `projectDir` is a `package main` runtime, hence your `go run main.go` statement.  It's within this `main.go` (and anything else within this `main` package) that would reference your db code with `import "./db"`.  And, make sure it is all in your `$GOPATH/src/`.

Comment: Sorry I've add the project structure for more clarification.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Another thing about referring to local packages: if you are constantly modifying that package, you need to keep refreshing it with `go install gitlab.com/myname/projectdir/db`.  The `go build` tool does some caching of import pages.  Running `go install` forces that package's cache to be refreshed.  Try it and let me know.

Comment: Still not working. Also, when I just ran `go build` inside `db` directory, the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Test functions should start with Test. that is what the documentation says.

```
func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    result := Add(a, b)
    if result != 3 {
        t.Errorf("expected 3, got %d ", result)
    }
 }
```

Cheers.